# How to pull out all routes for specific resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have strange question. I want in my helper to have array of paths that are available for specific resource.For example, if we have a model Comment I want to have an array which will have the following elements: [new_comment_path, comments_path] etc. Is this possible to do?

Edit:
I build left side menu in rails. It will work like tree menu. I don't want to use external plugins. Only thing that i must do is to have a all paths for my models.

Comment: What's the reason for this? Can you give us some more context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
Rails.application.routes.routes.map{|x| x.name}.reject{|x| x.blank?}
```

Which will get all named routes.  I'm not sure if there is a way of just getting routes for one resource though